# Script portability to MacOS

Tags: ghostscript, pdftk

## Context

Catalina (zsh) & Homebrew: man pages return successfully for `pdftk` & `ps2pdf`

The goal is to execute: [pdfBatesStamp.sh](https://pastebin.com/7kfV2Rp0) as described in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115537/182280

I changed the first line of the script to: `#!/bin/zsh -`

## Observations

Preliminary test returned:

[image]

The error: `: command not foundine XX:` are lines with no commands / comments.  Screenshot shows lines 104,105,109,111 are null:

[image]

UPDATE: said error is remedied by placing a # at the start of the line.

Line 132:

[image]

## Questions

1. What exactly is causing said errors?
2. What is the remedy?
3. Is there any reason that this script will NEVER run in said context?

## For jsbillings

```
user@JUPITER pdfBatesStamp % ./pdfBatesStamp.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf
./pdfBatesStamp.sh:59: command not found: ^M
./pdfBatesStamp.sh:132: parse error near `elif'
user@JUPITER pdfBatesStamp % 
user@JUPITER pdfBatesStamp % sh pdfBatesStamp.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf
pdfBatesStamp.sh: line 132: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'dfBatesStamp.sh: line 132: `elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
```

Ubuntu 16.04 Test results:

```
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ cp pdfBatesStamp.sh test.sh
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ dos2unix test.sh
dos2unix: converting file test.sh to Unix format ...
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ ls
Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf  pdfBatesStamp.sh  test.sh
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ ls -l
total 11384
-rw------- 1 user user 11589045 Nov 23 18:00 Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user    32764 Nov 23 22:24 pdfBatesStamp.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user    32764 Nov 23 22:26 test.sh
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ ./test.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf 
Input File = "/home/user/Desktop/BatesStamp/Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf"  (origSize=11,589,045)
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./test.sh: line 384: [: too many arguments
*** Can't find page size
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ mac2unix test.sh
mac2unix: converting file test.sh to Unix format ...
user@azimuth:~/Desktop/BatesStamp$ ./test.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf 
Input File = "/home/user/Desktop/BatesStamp/Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf"  (origSize=11,589,045)
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./test.sh: line 384: [: too many arguments
*** Can't find page size
```

Comment: run `dos2unix` and/or `mac2unix` on the file and try again.  Sounds like you have some bad line endings.

Comment: Did you install bash?  Why are you running a bash script with /bin/sh?

Comment: @jsbillings I do not think I installed bash. `./pdfBatesStamp.sh.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf` returned errors so I tried `sh pdfBatesStamp.sh.sh Exhibits_ActivityReport.pdf`

Comment: What errors did the bash command return?  And if you could update your question, please use text and not hard to read pictures.

Comment: @jsbillings Please see eponymous section of OP: is this the information requested?  I think Catalina uses zsh and I changed the first line of the script to `#!/bin/zsh -`

Comment: So is your question how to convert a bash script to zsh?  You are still running it in POSIX shell compatibility mode, so really the question is how to convert it to POSIX sh.

Comment: A lot of these errors look like you didn’t clean up the dos new lines. I agree with the other commenter on using `dos2unix`.

Comment: @jsbillings.  I agree and felt that the newline, CR was the culprit so I ran `dos2unix` on Ubuntu16.04 and posted the results.  Not what I had hoped for \ expected